# How to choose a good PhD student in pure mathematics?

Tags: graduate-education

I have some personal criterion to choose my graduate students including PhDs. Here I would like to know what my colleagues' criterion are to choose their math PhD/MSc students. I hope this may help me to note some subtle points which are important but less well-known about choosing a math PhD student. In fact I would like to know more on those useful abilities which a math PhD student should have.

> **Question:** What are nice criterion to choose a good PhD student in pure mathematics?

Comment: Academia.SE is a better fit. It's not education per se and even less specific to mathematics. I don't know how it would be possible to reformulate the question to become on-topic here. I agree it is a nice and useful question, though.

Comment: This seems to be a similar question there, but from the student's perspective: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/why-would-one-choose-a-particular-advisor-other-than-having-shared-interests/

Comment: Students often ask a professor to be their doctoral thesis adviser. The issue then becomes under what circumstances to agree to do this.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Academia.SE, as others have alluded to.